# seabornで棒グラフを描きたいのですが、edgecolorをpeletteで色分けするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

Tags: python

画像のようにedgecolorが色分けされてしまうですが、stripplotと同じように色わけするにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import random

%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'E' :pd.Categorical(['A', 'A','A','A','B', 'B','B','B','A', 'A','A','A','B', 'B','B','B']),
                        'F' :pd.Categorical([ 'C','C','C','C', 'C','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','D','D','D','D']),
                        'G' : random.sample(range(30), k=16)})

sns.set_style('ticks')
sns.set_context('poster', rc={'axes.titlesize':10, 'axes.labelsize':10, 'xtick.labelsize':10})
plt.subplot()
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=[15, 15]
clrs=['b', 'y']

ax=sns.barplot(x="F", y="G", hue="E", data=df, errwidth=2, capsize=0.15, errcolor='k', dodge=True, facecolor=(1, 1, 1, 0),
               linewidth=4,edgecolor=clrs)
sns.stripplot(x="F", y="G", hue="E", data=df, palette=clrs, linewidth=0, dodge=True, size=15)

ax.set_ylim([0, 10])

from matplotlib import ticker
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1)) 
sns.despine()
ax.legend(loc="lower left", bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1., 1.0, 0.05), mode="expand", ncol=3)

columncounts = [30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30,30]
def normaliseCounts(widths,maxwidth):
    widths = np.array(widths)/float(maxwidth)
    return widths
widthbars = normaliseCounts(columncounts,90)
for bar,newwidth in zip(ax.patches,widthbars):
    x = bar.get_x()
    width = bar.get_width()
    centre = x+width/2.

    bar.set_x(centre-newwidth/2.)
    bar.set_width(newwidth)
```

Comment: この記事あたりが参考になるかも。[How to set same colors for same indexes in different charts in matplotlib and seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54250974/9014308)

Answer (score 1):

どうも`palette`と`edgecolor`は色の割り当て順番の考え方が別々となっているようで、1つの`barplot`や`stripplot`の中で`palette`と`edgecolor`の両方に同じカラーのリストを指定しても同じ色にはならないようです。

何かテクニックがあれば実現出来るのかもしれませんが、それよりは簡単に思い付く代替案にしてみました。

それぞれソースの変更行と表示結果を載せます。
あとY軸の範囲とか少し数字を変更しています。

1. `barplot`と`stripplot`の両方の`palette`を同じにする
   ただしそうすると`barplot`のバーと`stripplot`の丸が同じ領域にある場合に区別が付かなくなるので、`stripplot`の丸に別の`edgecolor`を指定する

   a. `barplot`の`edgecolor`は有りのままとする

```
ax=sns.barplot(x="F", y="G", hue="E", data=df, palette=clrs, errwidth=2, capsize=0.15, errcolor='k', dodge=True, linewidth=2, edgecolor=clrs)
sns.stripplot(x="F", y="G", hue="E", data=df, palette=clrs, linewidth=1, dodge=True, size=10, edgecolor='r')
```

[image]

b. `barplot`の`edgecolor`を無しとする

```
ax=sns.barplot(x="F", y="G", hue="E", data=df, palette=clrs, errwidth=2, capsize=0.15, errcolor='k', dodge=True)
sns.stripplot(x="F", y="G", hue="E", data=df, palette=clrs, linewidth=1, dodge=True, size=10, edgecolor='r')
```

[image]

2. `stripplot`の`edgecolor`を表示することとし、`barplot`と`stripplot`の両方の`edgecolor`を同じにする

```
ax=sns.barplot(x="F", y="G", hue="E", data=df, errwidth=2, capsize=0.15, errcolor='k', dodge=True, facecolor=(1, 1, 1, 0), linewidth=2, edgecolor=clrs)
sns.stripplot(x="F", y="G", hue="E", data=df, palette=clrs, linewidth=2, dodge=True, size=10, facecolor=(1, 1, 1, 0), edgecolor=clrs)
```

[image]